# Does ci.gitlab.com support hosted Java builds?

Tags: java, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to understand what is provided by ci.gitlab.com. I would like to create a build using Gradle for my Java project and have it all run on ci.gitlab.com servers.

The process for adding a runner seems to involve leveraging a localized installation of GitLab CI. There are shared runners available, but they seem to be geared toward Ruby, Node, etc.

Is it possible to use ci.gitlab.com for a fully hosted CI solution?

Comment: Any update on this yet? I'm experiencing the same problem. Makes me want to switch to github.

Comment: I haven't had any success with this at all. We're planning to move to a local GitLab repository instead.

Answer (score 1):

Its not important if there are only Ruby, Node or other Runners. If they are shared runners, you can specify the image in your .gitlab-ci.yml which the runners use to run you tests. See here (i wrote a example .gitlab-ci.yml):

[image]

The runners will pull the right image and will run your tests in the specified image.
More information [here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html).